# jquery get returns an object with html entities decoded

Tags: jquery, ajax

when I try to do a get request using JQ, I get an object back and it decodes these guys <>

what can i possibly do to encode them?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: @EvoD, I think he wants them encoded as &lt; &gt;

Comment: no lol, sorry i was really hungry when I wrote this.  I want them decoded :) i'm using JQote and it's a template file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the expected response type is XML, you should change the server's response to escape the text.

If not, then you should have your server respond with JSON like so: `{"text": "<this is my text!>"}` and use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) on the client.